# How to resolve type difference while using std::count function to count number of items in vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stdvector, counting

I have a vector of struct type Item (`vector<Item>`) named boat_list that will be holding Items.

I am trying to use the std::count function to count instances of Item type based on the example code found from C++ Reference:

`int mycount = std::count (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 20);`

but am getting an error that is related to a type difference:

```
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:60,
                 from Boat.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item> >; _Value = const int]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:3194:12:   required from ‘typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::__count_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const int>; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4084:29:   required from ‘typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::count(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item> >; _Tp = int; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]’
Boat.h:48:66:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Item’ and ‘const int’)
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is the function where my error is occuring:

```
        int type = boat_list.at(i).item_number;
        int type_count = count(boat_list.begin(), boat_list.end(), type); //Error occurs here @line 48:66
        for (int j = i + 1; j < boat_list.size(); j++) {
            if (type = boat_list.at(j).item_number) {
                continue;
            }
```

I thought that there should be no error while using this method since I was using an int stored in boat_list named `item_number`.
Is the issue cause by using a vector of type Item?

Comment: You need to use std::count_if and provide a comparison function for example as a lambda.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik removed images.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is not defined the `operator ==` for objects of the type `Item` and the type `int` as the error message says.

You need to use the algorithm `std::count_if` providing a comparison function as for example

```
int type_count = std::count_if( boat_list.begin(), boat_list.end(), 
                                [&type]( const auto &item )
                                {
                                    return  item.item_number == type;
                                } );
```

Instead of the type `int` of the variable `type_count` it would be better to use at least the type specifier `auto`

```
auto type_count = std::count_if( /*...*/ );
```

Comment: I tried using the example given and while it did remove my errors and complete the make, the `print()` function that the code was residing in is not completing the necessary printing of information past the example you gave.

Comment: @Stanky-kun I answered your question. As for your new problem then I can say nothing because there is not provided the corresponding code. You should close the question selecting the best answer and then open a new question with your new problem.